# Integration testing the entity framework - separate the seed method call only for PROD -

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, integration-testing

I want to **integration test** my repositories.

I want to setup and insert test data before each integration test method.
Then I want to execute my repository logic
Then I want to assert that the logic works by returning the correct data from the database.

I do not want to mock and unit test the DbSet ;-) just real integration tests.

My question is about the whole setup of the database and clearing the test data.

I use code first approach generating a **TestDatabase** and **ProdDatabase**. In the ProdDatabase I **seed** real data to play then with it in the UI and check the correct behavior. The TestDatabase is just for the integration tests.

**Both** databases are created from **ONE** context.

When I change any property of an entity and I run my integration tests then the overwritten Seed method from my DbContext is called too. But I do not want that for my TestDatabase.

How can I separate the Seed call happen only for my ProdDatabase? And my TestDatabase generates its own "seed"/setup data per test?

Comment: which `IDatabaseInitializer` are you using?

Comment: The CreateDatabaseAlways.

Comment: no... this is a little private app ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In each case, you can [set a different](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461(v=vs.113).aspx) `IDatabaseInitializer` or `DbMigrationsConfiguration` (if you're using `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` for your initializer) during application startup:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new TestOrProdInitializer());
```

You can even set the database initializer using different [configuration file settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx#Initializers) for production vs. test:

> ```
> <contexts> 
>   <context type=" Blogging.BlogContext, MyAssembly"> 
>     <databaseInitializer type="Blogging.MyCustomBlogInitializer, MyAssembly" /> 
>   </context> 
> </contexts>
> ```

If you need to reseed after dropping the database, you can also force initialization with `dbContext.Database.Initialize(true)`.

Comment: how can I force the creation of the database with c# BEFORE I query the context? I thought context.Database.Initialize(true) is doing that but after the code run the database still has the old data so it was not deleted.

Comment: you could try `context.Database.Delete`? though technically it should already be called (see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679506(v=vs.113).aspx)). Maybe you could call SetInitializer right before calling initialize.

Comment: but context.Database.Delete does not create the database when I do the ctx.database.Initialize(true).

Comment: so I did ctx.database.delete()/then create() in the assembly initialize because within a test run using transactions I can not let the context query create a database that will result in an exception :-)

Comment: But of course this has nothing to do with my initial problem ;-)